# Back Button for "Previous Page"

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there a way to set the onClick to return to the previous page, rather than a specific page?

I have a print friendly page that is linked to by multiple pages. It would be nice if when users click "Back" they are returned to the page they just came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, here is a function that you can add to your client script file and call from any widget event handler:

```js
/**
 * Navigates user to a previous page.
 */
function goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}
```